# Completion of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathbb A, m)$ be a measurable space. Let $(Y, \mathbb B, v)$ a second measure space and $(X, \bar{\mathbb A}, \bar{m})$ , $(Y, \bar{\mathbb B}, \bar{v})$ other spaces, where $\bar{\mathbb A}$ denotes the completion of $\mathbb A$ with respect to $m$.

Now, if $f: (X, \mathbb A) \to (Y, \mathbb B)$ is a measurable function and $m(f^{-1} (B)) = 0$ for any $B \in \mathbb B$ such that $v(B) = 0$ : Why is $f: (X, \bar{\mathbb A}) \to (Y, \bar{\mathbb B})$ also measurable?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $B\in\Bbb B$ is a null set, that is, that $v(B)=0$. Then the completion of $\Bbb B$ ensures that if $A\subset B$ then $\bar v(A)=0$. And because $f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(B)$ then we find that $\bar m(f^{-1}(A))=0$ because $m(f^{-1}(B))=0$ and now $\Bbb A$ is complete. Then $f$ is also measurable in the completion of the measure spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I've understood correctly, does it hold $\bar{f(m)} = f(\bar{m})$ ?

Comment: @StMan maybe you mean $f(\bar{\Bbb A})=\overline{f(\Bbb A)}$? Yes, it holds.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. But why does this hold? I don't see this yet :/

Comment: @StMan this is a different question. My answer show that the preimage of every element of $\bar{\Bbb B}$ is also measurable. Note that, by assumption, we already knows that $f^{-1}(B)\in\Bbb A$ for any chosen $B\in\Bbb B$. Then, after the completion, we only need to check that this also holds for any subset of a null set. Check the definition of [measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition).